# "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Tried to use EndUserViewModel after `dispose` was called. Consider checking `mounted`."

Tags: flutter, riverpod

```
EndUserViewModel? endUserViewModel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if(mounted){
      loadEndUser();
    }
  }

  loadEndUser() async {

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      endUserViewModel = ref.read(endUserViewModelProvider.notifier);
      await endUserViewModel?.fetchEndUser("user02@gmail.com");

      final endUser =  endUserViewModel?.endUserList;
      final endUserData = endUser?.first.name;
      print(" DATA $endUser");
      print("USER $endUserData");

    });

  }
```

I am trying to fetch the data from the API using this function in `initState()`,
but it shows the error-

> E/flutter (14175): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Tried to use EndUserViewModel after `dispose` was called.
> E/flutter (14175):
> E/flutter (14175): Consider checking `mounted`.

I have also used `ConsumerStateful` for the class and checked the mounted but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (mounted) {
      loadEndUser();
    }
  });
  super.initState();
}

loadEndUser() async {
  endUserViewModel = ref.read(endUserViewModelProvider.notifier);
  await endUserViewModel?.fetchEndUser("user02@gmail.com");

  final endUser = endUserViewModel?.endUserList;
  final endUserData = endUser?.first?.name;
  print("DATA $endUser");
  print("USER $endUserData");
}
```

Hello, move the if (mounted) check inside the WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback() callback, this ensure that the loadEndUser() method is only called if the widget is still mounted. This check is necessary because the addPostFrameCallback() method schedules a callback to be called after the frame is rendered. If the widget is unmounted before the frame is rendered, the callback will not be executed.

Comment: And you should always check after async methods, that a StatefulWidget is still mounted. In this case use an if (mounted) after the fetchUser method.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but still error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (mounted) {
      loadEndUser();
    }
  });
  super.initState();
}

loadEndUser() async {
  endUserViewModel = ref.read(endUserViewModelProvider.notifier);
  await endUserViewModel?.fetchEndUser("user02@gmail.com");
  
  if (mounted) {
    final endUser = endUserViewModel?.endUserList;
    final endUserData = endUser?.first?.name;
    print("DATA $endUser");
    print("USER $endUserData");
  }
}
```

dragonpicari is right, but be sure to always check, that the widget is still mounted after async methods.
But in this case the post frame callback is not necessary, you are able to load it in initState().

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but still error is showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        loadEndUser();
        print("DATA ${endUserViewModel?.endUserList}");
        print("USER ${endUserViewModel?.endUserList?.first.name}");
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  loadEndUser() async {

    if (mounted) {
      endUserViewModel = ref.read(endUserViewModelProvider.notifier);
      await endUserViewModel?.fetchEndUser("user02@gmail.com");

    }
  }
```

Comment: It works now. I have moved the print() and It does not shows any error.

Comment: what is the point of doing the `mounted` check twice? I think in `loadEndUser` it may be necessary only if you try to call this method after `onTap`.